# Why selecting nodes in shading mode is not working?

Tags: animation, node-editor, shaders

I clicked on B then with the mouse left button hold down dragging it top cover the nodes. I want to select the 4 nodes but when I'm leaving the mouse left button the selection is gone.

[image: Box Select]

I want to duplicate this 4 nodes so they will keep be connected only between them self. Like this :

[image: Duplicate]

Comment: You don't need B, just hold down left mouse button. The nodes that have been selected will have an orange outline. Click and drag the top bar of one of the selected nodes to move the whole group. You can duplicate selected nodes or node groups with shift+D.

Comment: @ChristopherBennett You *do* have to press 'B' if you have changed the active tool in the node editor from 'Select Box' to something else, otherwise left click and drag will activate the current tool.